# How to design classes for a testable, pythonic, OOP simple test log parser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pytest

**Situation:**
The test suite is executed several times. After every run it appends results of test cases to its log file.

**Mission to accomplish:**
Crawl through the log, find the results for all test cases for all runs, return a dict in a form `{test_case_name:{'passed':times_passed, 'failed':times_failed}}`.

**Bonus tasks to accomplish:**
Check log for consistency, unexpected fails etc.

My first idea was to create two classes, to fulfill the Chain of responsibility pattern:

> Every piece of code must do one, and only one, thing.

First of them would be `Log` responsible for opening and reading a file with `log_checker` and `list_cases_names` methods. The second class would be `TestCaseResult` with methods such as `add_result`, `count_passrate` etc.

While trying to accomplish the task in TDD I found it impossible to create good-looking unit tests for that (I'm using py.test). To create `TestCaseResult` object I need to have list of cases names from `Log` class. And here comes the question: does it mean that I should improve my class design? Is there a better approach or some best practices to create testable classes interacting with each other?

Comment: That looks wrong. Any list of cases names should do, it should not matter whether it comes from a `Log` class or not.

Comment: @Goyo thanks for your input! I wanted to use real life logs for unit testing, is it wrong approach? Is it a better practice to make 'syntetic' unit tests and feed them with example predetermined data?

Comment: Thechnically that is not unit testing, looks more like end-to-end testing. It is fine. But then I do not understand the problem. You need a list of cases names from `Log`, you can have it.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. Probably class design is ok, I should just improve unit tests. Thanks!

Comment: If you find it hard to test that might be a signal that something is wrong in the design. But without more details is not possible to go beyond that.